# Timestamping in digital signature in a signed xml

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature

There is a requirement for capturing the date-time of signing while digitally signing the XML document. This timestamp is required to be embedded in the document/ signature itself and to be used during verification. How can it be done. The examples available on google search show ways of adding timestamp in signature properties as meta information but do not consider it during verification. In fact that way timestamp is not binded to the signature and can be changed without failing the signature verification. I have already implemented XML signing without timestamp. The project is in C# DotNet4.5.2  .Please guide!

Comment: I guess you tagged it C# because you need it coded in C#, right?

Comment: Yes. I am using c# DotNet 4.5.2 . I've added it to question now. Thanks

Comment: And what is the difference between adding the timestamp after signing and adding the timestamp after verifying ?